# custom URL mappings in codeigniter like redmine?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redmine

So redmine has a very peculiar url mapping style that i observed :

```
http://demo.redmine.org/projects/<project-name>/controller/action
```

samples :

```
http://demo.redmine.org/projects/produto/activity
http://demo.redmine.org/projects/produto/issues/new
http://demo.redmine.org/projects/produto/issues/gantt
http://demo.redmine.org/projects/produto/files
```

and the url changes as the project changes.

how do i do this in codeigniter ? I'm thinking it can be done with routes.php but so far i'm not able to get anywhere.

Looking for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following function inside your "application/controllers/projects.php" controller:

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'project-name')
    {
        //display project1
    }
    elseif($method == 'project-name2')
    {
        //display project2
    }
}
```

You can do the same for varying methods by extracting them from database

take a look here: 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

you can also route your controller by using custom routes in application/config/routes.php

```
$route['example'] = "controller/function";
$route['example2/(:any)'] = "controller/function";
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the routes file in application/config/routes.php
You would use something like this:

```
// the $1 maps to :any
$route['projects/produto/:any'] = "$1";

// the $1 maps to the first any, $2 maps to the second :any
$route['projects/produto/:any/:any'] = "$1/$2";
```

You will want mod_rewrite enabled if you are handling clean URL's. Otherwise expect the index.php/controller/action. I cant test it myself there, but you should refer to:

Once you add a route (It has to be called $route[] inside the configuration), refresh the page and try to go to the URL!

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: in your exmaples the controller actions do not know which project is selected!

Comment: You might have to hard code it in.. Otherwise you could try... $route['projects/:any/:any'] = "$1/$2";

Answer (score 0):

add this to your routes.php (btw: you need url-rewriting enabled for routes to work, ie. using `.htaccess`)

```
$route['projects/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "$2/$3/$1";
```

for example `/projects/produto/issues/new` will call the function new in the class issues and pass it the parameter 'produto'

also check http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html